# Eclipse PDT (Helios) - prevent CSS editor from auto-closing rules with curly brace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Does anyone know where to find the preference to disable auto-insertion of closing curly braces when editing CSS files?  Typing 'div.classname { line-break line-break }' is by now second nature to me, but with the latest version of Eclipse PDT I always end up with this:

```
div.classname {

} /* <- extra bracket! Bad! */
```

}

...because the editor auto-inserts the closing brace for you.  I cannot seem to break myself of this habit and frankly I don't *want* to get out of the habit of typing in syntactically correct code.  I've been able to turn off all of the typing assist stuff for editing js and php files but there doesn't seem to be a similar preference for CSS files.  Has anyone come across it?

Many thanks in advance.